# Kile. Keyboard layout switching

Tags: kile

When working with text with Kile I use both Latin and Cyrillic keyboard layouts.

Shortcuts like Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z do work if layout is Latin, and do not work if layout is switched to Cyrillic.

Is there any hints or tricks to make it work independently of keyboard layout?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary to bind to this second values on cyrillic: Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Ч

KDE System Settings > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > KDE Component: KDE Activity Manager - Add custom shortcut

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't You navigate me to menu where to bind?

Comment: @SergeyShitov: Could you please [edit] your answer and copy-paste your comment there so the next person around doesn't have to read all the comments?  Спасибо!